# Proof that from FTA follows $n>\alpha_{n,k}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Recall the FTA in [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Canonical_representation_of_a_positive_integer)

$$n=p_1^{\alpha_{n,1}}p_2^{\alpha_{n,2}} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_{n,k}}
= \prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\alpha_{n,i}}$$

where $n,i,k \in\Bbb N$ and $\alpha \in\Bbb N_0$.

***Two questions:***

*(1) How can one proof that from FTA follows that: $n>\alpha_{n,k}$*

*(2) Is it possible to formulate a big-$O$ approximation in this repsect that is better than $\alpha_{n,k}=O(n)$*

Comment: $\alpha_{n,k}\in O(\log n)$?

Comment: Ah, I somehow missed the second part of the question. @LordSoth Will delete my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha_{n,k}$ Intuitively represents the number of distinct prime factors of $n$, so you are essentially asking for a good approximation on the number of distinct prime factors an integer has, the common notation for this function is $\omega(n)$. Unfortunately the behavior of this function is very erratic as you know there are infinitely many primes so we have that $\omega(n)=1$, infinitely often, on the other hand we can clearly create numbers so that $\omega$ grows with out bound. Thus the best possible bounds would be that $1\le \omega(n)\leq [\log_2(n)]$, however this does not reflect the 'average' behavior of $\omega$.
We can give a good estimate on the 'average' behavior, of $\omega(n)$,

For example we have that.

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\omega(n)=x\ln(\ln(x))+c_1x+O(\frac{x}{\ln(x)})$$

Which says that on 'average' we have $\omega(n)\approx \ln(\ln(n))$

Edit:

From your previous comment you seem to be asking about the average order of the largest exponent in the factorization of $n$, this function as I know doesn't have a current name, but a constant that appears in the asymptotic expansion of the summatory function for it does, it is called Niven's constant.

Here is Niven's original paper in which he gives a good estimate on the average order of the function you want, and a very similar function also: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-022-02/S0002-9939-1969-0241373-5/S0002-9939-1969-0241373-5.pdf

In it he defines $H(n)$ to be the largest exponent appearing in the factorization of $n$, and gives the estimate.

$$\sum_{n\leq x}H(n)=Cx+O(\sqrt{x}\ln(x))$$

Where $$C=1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(1-\frac{1}{\zeta(n)})$$

Is Niven's constant, so we might say that on average $H(n)\approx C=1.705211...$.

The best possible unconditional bounds for $H(n)$ would be the same as before with the $\omega$ function, they are $1\leq H(n) \leq [\log_2(n)]$. Which again as with the $\omega$ function these upper/lower bounds doesn't really reflect the 'average' value of $H(n)$.

Comment: I have to get back to your answer see here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html the number of distinct prime factors is the index of $\alpha$ but nut $\alpha$ itself. In the canonical form above $\alpha_{n,k}$ is the largest exponent in the prime factorisation of $n$. Or I probably misunderstood you. May you help?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi Yes, I seem to have misunderstood you, let me update you, there are in-fact better estimates for the 'average' order of this function.

Comment: great stuff! Thanks! It shows me to where can take next step and also to which extend there is yet a solution to this available. One thing out of excitement the Erdös conjecture for the lower bound connects probably to the Critical temperature in Bose Einstein condensates. This $\zeta(3/2)$ mus have some deep mathematical intuition on its back. Thanks again for great contribution.

Answer (score 4):

hint:

2 is the smallest prime, $2^{\alpha_{n,k}}>\alpha_{n,k}$